# Informatica : Sequence generate

Tags: informatica

Without using sequence generator ***How can we generate sequences in informatica mapping*** ?

Thanks

Comment: Please do your own homework. Or at least show some effort and ask a specific question where you are stuck.

Comment: Am new to informatica.. tried to do this with a variable in expression. but the value is not getting changed.

Comment: Could you show us what you have tried?

Comment: I habve tried using setCountVariable().

Answer (score 1):

Well, like others said, I would have preferred to get a specific question on why you are trying to avoid sequence generator.  Having said that, if i open myself to "the idea of an alternate" to sequence generator, some things do come to mind

1. If you have a relatively simplistic mapping, you can embed a oracle/db sequence.nextval call hidden in the source qualifier.
2. you can embed db/sequence call in a sql tranformation too. But know that it would be anti-performant.
3. you will be able to achieve a sequence generator behaviour using a persistent variable too, but there are limitations and downsides.

So, again, depending upon what you are trying to do and where you are getting stuck, you might want to repost/edit your question.. and perhaps get a more direct answer.