# how to create a sequence without using mapping variables and sequence generator?

Tags: sequence, informatica-powercenter, informatica

I had a scenario where i have to generate a sequence without using sequence transformation

i can do the same using mapping variables like using the `setcountvariable()` option it works but is there any other solution for the same.

Thanks

Comment: Duplicate of [Informatica : Sequence generate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13350911/informatica-sequence-generate) - What do people keep asking this? Is this some popular interview question?

Comment: What's wrong with a sequence generator or a variable? Why are you trying to avoid them? Is calling a procedure to get an ID value from an Oracle sequence an option?

Answer (score 1):

here unconnected lookup you are using for only getting count or max of sequence from target table.
we can also achive this by using stored procedure transformation.

Answer (score 0):

1. **using unconnected lookup and expression transformation**
2. **create unconnected lookup to get max sequence value from target for that you have to override a query which will give you max value**
3. **return that max value port to expression transformation**
4. **now create one variable port with increment by 1 and add with max value it wil create sequence value for evry record passing to target table**